# glDrawElements not working in the other machine

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault, vertex-array, gldrawarrays

I'm using OpenGL with g++. This simple code works fine in my system. It draws a rectangle as expected.

```
GLfloat vertices[] = 
{
    0,0,0,  //0
    0,6,0,  //1
    6,6,0,  //2
    6,0,0,  //3
};
GLint indices[] = {0,1,2,3};
glColor3f(1,0,0);
glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
```

But in my friend's system, it gives segmentation fault.

I changed `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` to `GL_INT`. Then at least it does not give segmentation fault but its not rendering anything.

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: There si lots of GL state which might be relevant here. For example, do you have other arrays enabled?

Comment: I have `glEnableClientState (GL_COLOR_ARRAY);` and `glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);`. Do I need to have anything else?

Comment: In the code above, there is no color array. So if you have this still enabled from some previous draw call, you must explicitely disable it.

Comment: It would make more sense if you post more of the relevant code. Since OpenGL acts as a state machine there's a lot we can miss looking at a snippet of the code.

Answer (score 0):

*Read your documentation carefully*

Don't forget to `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);`

Comment: I've added this. That's why its working in my system.

Comment: So what is your question here?

Comment: Its giving `segmentation fault` when I run it my friend's system

Comment: Please do correct the code in question (add glEnableClientState) and give some info on the machine your friend has.